# SceneManager.GetActiveScene(); return -1 when Debugging active scene in editor

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to use the new SceneManagement since Application.LoadLevel is obscelete and I've read that we need to put it like this.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class UI : MonoBehaviour {

    private Scene activeScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log (activeScene.name);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void restartLevel(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene (activeScene.buildIndex);
    }
}
```

The Debug.Log show "-1" and it should be "0" and throw this error in console

```
Scene '' (-1) couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to the build settings or the AssetBundle has not been loaded.
```

The Scene is added in the build setting too by the way.

Seems that it can't return me the good index and even with the activeScene.name, still returns NULL. I miss how Application.LoadLevel was easier and more robust that this new way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh.. You are assigning `activeScene` outside the main thread. Just assign it in any method such as `Start` or `Awake`.

Like,

```
...
private Scene activeScene;
...

void Start () {
        activeScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        Debug.Log (activeScene.name);
    }
...
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you add the Scene in Building Settings?

sceneNumber = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;

by this code you will get scene number.

Comment: "The Scene is added in the build setting too by the way."

Comment: sceneNumber = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;

by this code you will get scene number.

Comment: First you try to get scene name.To restart the game you used index number those are different . Try my code please you will solve it. Otherwise please let me know.